# "Downward closed" relation on a poset

Tags: reference-request, order-theory, posets

I say that a relation $R$ on a poset $P$ is *downward closed* if for each $(x,y)\in R$, and $x'\le x$, then $(x',y)\in R$.
Is there a reference where this thing is studied, maybe under a different name?

The motivation for this question is: I'm trying to prove or disprove that the lower/upper consistency relations, as defined in §1.3 [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.2549), have this property.

Comment: Downward closed sets are sometimes called "order ideals".

Comment: This is just a set-mapping $P\to D(P)$, where $D(P)$ is the set of all downward closed sets of $P$. Never heard of anyone studying this strange kind of animal. However, if you would want to know something about *isotone* mappings $P\to D(P)$, that would be another story, of course.

Comment: Relations for which $x'\leq x R y\leq y'\Longrightarrow x' R y'$ are most certainly a very common kind of animal.   Mappings $X\to T X$ for any endofunctor of any category are another very common kind of animal, called a **coalgebra**, which enough people study to run a conference series.